# Get pyglet event in PyQt program

Tags: python, qt, audio, pyqt, pyglet

I want to implement a music playlist like feature into my Qt program. And after some research I settled for Pyglet to read my music. For two reasons, the first one being it's easy to load differently encoded files and also because you pause and queue songs with the `media.Player` object.

My problem is that now I would like to know when a music or what's queued in the `Player` ends, to ensure that music keeps playing if it needs to.

So far my code is like this to create the `Player` and get it to play music:

```
    self.player = pyglet.media.Player()

    self.player.queue(media.load(self.listening.pop(0).getPath()))
    self.playing = True
    self.player.play()
```

I know that `Player` has `on_eos` `on_player_eos` and `on_group_eos` events attached to it, the problem is that I don't have a pyglet app launched so I think I can't handle those events.

I would like to know how to do if it's possible, and if it's not (or way too complicated like threadpool for medias) is there an other library that can handle at least mp3 and wav reading with the possiblity to stop the listening and start back at the same point later.

For the record I need this solution to be easily deployable on a Window machine, because I saw `musicplayer` and could not get it to work on my computer

Comment: With PyQt5 there is [QMediaPlayer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html).

Comment: Smart idea, done this, took me the whole day to transfer from Qt4 but it worked. Thanks!